# How can subscripts converge to $\infty$ almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is the question:

Give an example of random variables $X_n \in \{0,1\}$, $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability, $N(n) \uparrow \infty$ almost surely and $X_{N(n)} \rightarrow 1$ almost surely.

Here is MY question: 
Is $N(n)$ a random variable? Do we in otherwords have an increasing sequence of random variables: $N(1), N(2), \ldots$ which converge to $\infty$ almost surely?

Comment: There seems to be some context missing. How is $N(n)$ defined in what you are reading (or the question is just as is written)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here $N(n)$ is a random variable. It is supposed to converge to $\infty$ in probability, that is, for each $A\gt 0$, $\mathbb P\{|N(n)|\leqslant A\}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

In order to solve the problem, we can take $X_n:=\chi_{A_n}$, where $\mathbb P(A_n)\to 0$ and $\limsup_nA_n=\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

take independent $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $X_n = 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and otherwise 0, then $X_n$ converge in probability to 0.

But since $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} = +\infty$, according to Borel-Cantelli lemma, almost surely there are infinitely many $n$ such that $X_n =1$. We define $N(n)$ as index of the n-th X taking value of 1, then $N(n)$ converging to $+\infty$ almost surely